# Control persisted WF instance (xamlx) without AppFabric

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation, appfabric, xamlx

I have a workflow service (xamlx) which implements some complex business process (with persistence and correlation).  This service is hosted in IIS and I use AppFabric to control workflow instanses (Terminate them or Cancel).

Now I need to allow users, who don't have administrative rights and, hence, access to AppFabric to stop workflows (Terminate) if they make mistakes while invoking it and restart the workflow.

Is it possible to implement the same logic as it is used in AppFabric with C# code (I plan to create a web service with the help of which it would be possible to terminate workflows)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AppFabric use a [Workflow Control Endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358723.aspx) to handle all commands you issue using the UI. You can use the [WorkflowControlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activities.workflowcontrolclient.aspx) in your code to do the same thing. Note that by default the AppFabric used the NetNamedPipeBinding which only allows for local connections so you might need to add another binding like the BasicHttpBinding.

Comment: Thank you a lot. The only proble that was left with that approach - to configure standard endpoint